# Why do Marvel Comics' Celestials appear to have humanoid forms?

Tags: marvel, comics

According to [this](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Celestials_(Race)#Powers) and their depictions in the comics, Celestials can remain levitated in the air and maneuver in any direction. If they could just fly anywhere they want and constantly remain floating in the air effortlessly, why do they need legs?

[image: A group of Celestials tower over a group of human superheros; some of the Celestials are stood on the ground; others are floating in the air]

Comment: Birds have legs. Without them landing is a pain in the butt.

Comment: Seriously. How is this not obvious?

Comment: What about the characters that could potentially float indefinitely? Why do they need legs?

Comment: Now that it's focused on Celestials, it's still not a great question but there is a pretty reasonable canon answer - |Voting to reopen

Comment: Ancient astronaut theory? Celestials don't have legs due to a need for them to look more human, but rather, humans have legs due to the influence of Celestials. Because aliens! (insert random picture of Giorgio A. Tsoukalos and his hair). Timing for Celestial appearence in comics is not to long after http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chariots_of_the_Gods_(film) so maybe a link after all.

Answer (score 1):

When the Celestials become bodiless, they failed to realise that this would result in the destruction of their race. They lost the ability to do anything other than move and influence, including losing the ability to procreate. They recognised that, over galactic timescales they would all die and that without new Celestials, their race would become extinct.

They lit on a plan to implant celestial embryos inside planets and then to influence/trick the inhabitants into defending the embryos against outside attack. **Part of this influence appears to be appearing in a form that most humanoids would recognise and instinctively view as godly rather than simply being alien.**

[image: A group of Celestials hover in space surrounded by planets, a narrator talks about their past and their plan to to implant celestial embryos inside planets as described above]

There's also a reasonable possibility that the legs are more than just an affectation. The Celestials *may* have been humanoid before becoming energy-beings. That being the case, the legs would be a comfortable and familiar way to get around.

[image: The Three Gods of Earth bow down to the Celestial Arishem and pledge not to impede the Celestial's progress for a millennium. In the background another Celestial flies through the sky alongside a massive space ship away from the Earth Gods]